# Python `cbor` encode np.float32 as float

Tags: python, cbor

Trying to encode in cbor some `list`s and `dict`s which may have *deeply nested* numpy `float32` values.

Although those values looks similar and interchangeable:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.float32(1.001)
y = 2.002
print(x, y) # 1.001 2.001
print(type(x), type(y)) # <class 'numpy.float32'> <class 'float'>
```

`cbor` would fail to encode np.float32:

```
import cbor
cbor.dumps([x, y])
# ValueError: cannot serialize unknown object: 1.001
```

I don't want or need to retain the `np.float32` type information, so I would be ok if `cbor` treats a `np.float32` (and similar) object just like a basic `float` object.

But I don't want to deeply scan and convert my object (which in this simplified case is `[x, y]`, but it is more complex in reality) as that would be a performance penalty.

Is there a way to register an encoder for `np.float32` so that I can convert the value to Python's `float` and encode it with default `cbor` ancoder?

Comment: Which cbor library are you using? Two are available on PyPi: [cbor](https://pypi.org/project/cbor/) and [cbor2](https://pypi.org/project/cbor2/). Your import suggests that you are using cbor, last release of which if from 2016. IMHO, you should considere to use cbor2 which is better maintained and that supports custom encoders.